# Windows 7 sounds tab missing

Tags: windows-7, audio, system-sounds

This "Sounds" tab is gone from my system:

[image]

I have sound on my laptop, anything I playback has sound, I can even switch theme profiles and sounds change (as evidenced by the "welcome" sound that I hear everytime I switch to a different desktop profile), but the sounds tab is gone.

I've already ran **sfc /scannow** and no errors were found.

*What causes this?*

Thanks .

Comment: Did you change the driver? Can you access it from Control Panel? Is it just the tab that has gone of the entire window?

Comment: Did not change the sound or any other driver. I can access the window via Control Panel or right clicking the speaker icon on the taskbar, only the "sounds" tab is missing.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of what you see?

Comment: Can't post right now the actual screen cap, but is basically the img from my original post without the selected tab. I only have Playback, Recording and Communications tabs. Will post later in the day.

Comment: @MauF Is the "Sounds"-option present if you right-click the loudspeaker-icon in the traybar near the time (like [this](http://i.imgur.com/42JwqBk.png))?

Comment: No, that's precisely what I'm missing from my system. I've updated the screen cap from one taken from my own Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Found the answer [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c8a3fadf-2780-4189-b5e2-50372b3d43ce/sounds-tab-missing-in-mmsyscpl-sound-control-panel-on-windows-7):

```
Run... regedit

HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization\

Name: NoChangingSoundScheme
Type: REG_DWORD
Data: 0x00000000 (0)

0 = Sounds Tab 
1 = No Sounds Tab
```

Still would like to know how this policy got changed.